# Encoding issue in "Featured on Meta" box

Tags: bug, status-review, community-bulletin, sidebar

This is what I currently see in the sidebar on Stack Overflow:

[image: "Don't" is rendered as "Don't" on "Featured on Meta" questions list]

Looks like the apostrophe is encoded one too many times.

This appears to randomly come and go as evidenced by [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410892) [reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415371).

Comment: Looks fine to me on Chrome/Windows. What browser are you using?

Comment: I saw the same issue a few minutes ago (Chrome/Win10), but it looks alright now. Maybe it got fixed?

Comment: I use Firefox Developer, but it looks OK to me too now.

Comment: I still see the problem using Chrome on Android.

Comment: It comes and goes. Most of the time it’s fine, but that just means it is harder to reproduce, not that the problem doesn’t exist.