# Eagerly escaping of HTML entities in featured community bulletin titles

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

Somehow, the apostrophe on the featured titles is being escaped, while the ones in the hot posts isn't.

[image: Instead of showing "Don't" in the title it shows "Don&39;t".]

Fox'plas?

Comment: MSE dupe: ["Featured on Meta" section showing apostrophes as &#39;](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368786)

Comment: I wonder what's causing this. it seems inconsistent user to user. I still see [correct apostrophes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkYVB.png), but clearly you're not the only one based on the MSE dupe.

Comment: i see it correct here, and incorrect on SO. Correction: it's fine on SO now. probably fixed already

Comment: @Nick sorry, but it can be reproduced.

Comment: @Braiam Then, maybe add a comment under the linked question and vote to reopen.

Comment: When trying to upvote my own post in SuperUser.com just now - "You can&#39;t vote for your own post"