# Featured on Meta section: "&" rendered as "&amp;" in question title

Tags: bug

I just noticed that in the "Featured on Meta" section the `&` in "Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story" is displayed as `&amp;`.  I am not sure but I think this hasn't been the case the last time I saw it there a few days ago.

[image: screenshot showing the issue]

Comment: Umm.... yeah... I'm sure this has happened before so it might be a regression of some sort... as I'm also fairly sure it was rendered as an actual `&` before now.

Comment: Previous reports: [Encoding issue in "Featured in Meta" box](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410837/8967612), [Eagerly escaping of HTML entities in featured community bulletin titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410892/8967612), and on MSE: ["Featured on Meta" section sometimes (but not always) showing apostrophes as &#39;](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368786/348196)

Comment: @JonClements I don't think it was ever fixed. It just happens from time to time and doesn't affect all posts ‍♂️

Comment: @41686d6564 Thanks, I assumed that this issue has already been reported before but apparently used the wrong search terms.  Should we close this one as duplicate?

Comment: I've closed it as a duplicate of what I think is the most appropriate link here. Thanks to @41686d6564 for tracking down the links. I'm going to leave it as status-review for now and revisit later.